# Creating the program of tokenization

Tags: java, tokenize, stringtokenizer

I need a help. I have to write a program of tokenization. I load a text file and split it into tokens, but I also need to display the final, initial position of the words and the word length (from text file). I’ll be very grateful to you for any help. I've been trying to do this for the past 3 days  with no luck, here is what I have done:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.*;

public class Tokenizer1 { 

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C://text.txt"));
    FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("C://result.txt");
    PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(fw);
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine()," ");
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        System.out.println(st.nextToken());
    } 
    String[] tokens = "".split(",");
    int tokenStartIndex = 0;
    for (String token : tokens) {
        for (String token : str.split(", ")) {
            System.out.println("token: " + token + ", tokenStartIndex: " +    tokenStartIndex);
            tokenStartIndex += token.length() + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your actual question or problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if you don't need to process the file line by line:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/text.txt");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int c;
    while((c = fis.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char)c);
    }
    fis.close();

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    System.out.println("---------------------");

    int start = 0;

    // OPTION 1: using String.split method
    String[] tokens = sb.toString().split("[\\s,]+");
    for(String t : tokens) {
        System.out.println("START: " + start + "\tLENGTH: " + t.length() + "\tWORD: " + t);
        start += t.length();
    }

    start = 0;

    // OPTION 2: using StringTokenizer class
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(sb.toString(), ",\t\n\f\r");
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String next = st.nextToken();
        System.out.println("START: " + start + "\tLENGTH: " + next.length() + "\tWORD: " + next);
        start += next.length();
    }
}
```

If you need to process the file line by line, you might wanna try this one:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/text.txt"));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    int lineNumber = -1;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        ++lineNumber;
        sb.append(line);
        System.out.println("\nLINE: " + lineNumber);
        int elementPosition = 0;

        // OPTION 1: using String.split method
        /*String[] lineContents = line.split("[\\s,]+");
        for (String content : lineContents) {
            System.out.println("\tSTART: " + elementPosition + "\tLENGTH: " + content.length() + "\tWORD: " + content);
            elementPosition += content.length();
        }*/

        // OPTION 2: using StringTokenizer class
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(sb.toString(), ",\t\n\f\r");
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String next = st.nextToken();
            System.out.println("\tSTART: " + elementPosition + "\tLENGTH: " + next.length() + "\tWORD: " + next);
            elementPosition += next.length();
        }
    }
    br.close();
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it works good, thanks a lot. But is it possible to perform tokenization from file using class StringTokenizer?

Comment: It's possible, however StringTokenizer is a legacy class: StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: I've edited the answer for you to include StringTokenizer solutions, too.

Comment: I see, thanks for helping me. And if I need to output all results in another file, I should use `FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("C://compile_results.txt");
PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(fw);`,Im right? and then using `System.out.println()` how i could I do this...

Comment: Yes, you're right, you need to use FileWriter and PrintWriter.  
`FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C://compile_results.txt");`  
`PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);`  
  
Calling System.out.println() will write to the standard output (usually the console) which is not what you want.  
What you want is to call  
`pw.print()` method to write the string to the file.  
After you finished writing, you should close the pw object by calling 
`pw.close()`.  
This will close the FileWriter as well.